# how to change dynamic value when we have to use pdfkit for creating the pdf in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

```
var fs = require('fs');
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

var pdf = new PDFDocument({
  size: 'LEGAL', // See other page sizes here: https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/d95b826475dd325fb29ef007a9c1bf7a527e9808/lib/page.coffee#L69
  info: {
    Title: 'Tile of File Here',
    Author: 'Some Author',
  }
});

// Write stuff into PDF
pdf.text('Hello World{a}');

// Stream contents to a file
pdf.pipe(
  fs.createWriteStream('/home/parmod/Desktop/file.pdf')
)
  .on('finish', function () {
    console.log('PDF closed');
  });

// Close PDF and write file.
pdf.end();
```

**so i have created successfully pdf.but i want to change some data in every pdf.so how to set dynamically value in  pdf template.pllz anybody solve my problem**

*i want to data  this format-----
name-vipin kumar
age-22
company-ibm

name-vikash kumar
age-23
company-cisco*

Comment: since u can write to the pdf, isnt changing data as simple as that? I don't get you on the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a new line after each entry. This should work:

```
["Name1 Age1 Company1","Name2 Age2 Company2"]
.forEach(function(v){
                 doc.text(v);
                 doc.moveDown();// should create a new line
});
```

Comment: can we use any template engine with pdfkit.like HTML,EJS,JADE etc

Comment: pdfkit is for generating custom pdfs. I believe you would want to write a method to extract data from your generated HTML and pass it to pdfkit in a templated format.